# grep not extracting desired string

Tags: unix, grep, command, ls

I'm working on the following question for my class (in Unix) and I'm running into some problems.

> Using the `grep` command and regular expressions, create a pipe-based
>   chain of commands that will list all files in the default directory
>   that others can read or write.

This is the command I have so far and it will correctly match the right lines, but I only want to to print the name of the file that has the desired permissions.

```
ls -la | grep "^.......rw.*:\d\d\s(.*)$"
```

here is the result of just typing `ls -la` by the way which is what I'm "greping"

```
total 344
drwxr-xr-x  10 cameronpattisall  staff     340 Apr  7 11:21 .
drwxr-xr-x   7 cameronpattisall  staff     238 Apr  7 11:22 ..
-rw-r--r--   1 cameronpattisall  staff    6148 Apr  7 11:21 .DS_Store
-rw-r--r--   1 cameronpattisall  staff   11591 Apr  7 11:21 DifferencesToTagged.txt
-rw-r--r--   1 cameronpattisall  staff    4291 Apr  7 11:21 functions.py
-rw-r--r--   1 cameronpattisall  staff    6080 Apr  7 11:21 ls.txt
-rw-r--r--   1 cameronpattisall  staff    5511 Apr  7 11:21 prog4.py
-rw-r--r--   1 cameronpattisall  staff     345 Apr  7 11:21 shared.py
-rw-r--r--   1 cameronpattisall  staff    1832 Apr  7 11:21 subversion-log.txt
-rw-r--r--   1 cameronpattisall  staff  122295 Apr  7 11:21 testcases.txt
```

Comment: What `grep` are you using? I don't think standard `grep` recognizes `\d` or `\s` or the parentheses. You might want to check the manual page. And if it did, you'd have an issue with some lines because `ls -l` doesn't show the time for old files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess the solution is to use:

```
grep -E "^-.{6}(r|.w)"
```

The structure of the first column is "-/d" (file/dir) + `xxx` (owner) + `xxx` (group) + `xxx` (others).

So you want to match those starting with `-` (file) and containing in the "gorup" part either `r..` or `.w.`.

To print just the file names, then you can pipe to `grep -o '[^ ]*$'`. This will print the last block of text. Note this is terrible fragile, since in a file name with spaces it will just print the last one.

#### Test

I stored your `ls -la` in the file `a`:

```
$ grep -E "^-.{6}(r|.w)" a | grep -o '[^ ]*$'
.DS_Store
DifferencesToTagged.txt
functions.py
ls.txt
prog4.py
shared.py
subversion-log.txt
testcases.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're already matching the right lines, you can append something like

`| tr -s ' ' | cut -d ' ' -f 9-` to your pipeline.

The `tr -s ' '` replaces multiple sequential spaces with a single space; the `cut` command removes everything except the ninth field onwards from each line, with fields delimited by single space characters.